# Обязательность использования тега main в html документе?

Tags: html

Я верстаю простой лендинг и мне нужно реализовать полноэкранный скролл по всем секциям(тег section) и header, для этого использую библиотеку  fullpage.js  только для её корректной работы требуется чтобы каждая секция была свободой и не во что не оборачивалась, но они обёрнуты в тег main, хотелось бы узнать можно ли обойтись без тега main и как это повлияет на семантику сайта?

Answer (score 0):

Он обязателен для семантики, но в случае если требуется не использовать его, вы можете указать ближайшему родителю роль - [`role="main"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80), он в свою очередь заменит `main`.

Но как по мне, гораздо проще переделать логику работы с Fullpage

Comment: @user558533, очепятка, должно было "переделать", если смотреть по документации `fullpage`, то там должен быть `div#fullpage` с дочерними `div.section`, при такой логике вам ничего не мешает использовать `main#fullpage` с дочерними `section.section`.